# After upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, nginx error 502: bad gateway until nginx is restarted

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, nginx

As the title suggests, I upgraded ubuntu server 14.04 to 16.04. I use nginx as my web server, and am also running a java/tomcat server, setup in my nginx config as a proxy_pass.

Since the upgrade, every time the server starts up nginx displays error `502: Bad Gateway` when attempting to connect to the proxy_pass site. All other sites specified in my config work as expected.

To resolve the issue, I must `sudo systemctl restart nginx`, after which, the proxy_pass service works.

I don't want to have to restart nginx every time I boot up. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this question at serverfault after 24 hours and I am going to include the resolution to my particular issue here for posterity..

In my configuration, the proxy_pass directive of the relevant nginx location block stated:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
```

However, the upstream service was actually binding to the ipv4 address, and is also slower to start at bootup than nginx.

When nginx checked the status of the upstream server, its connection was refused. Thereafter when nginx attempted to re-check the status of the upstream server, it continued to check only on the IPV6 address [::1].

To resolve the issue I specified the ipv4 address (127.0.0.1) instead of localhost, thus forcing nginx to use ipv4 only. It all works as expected, now.